# jQuery not loading on Master Page when the Content Page is in a child folder

Tags: asp.net, jquery

I have a site where I am trying to implement a jQuery UI based MessageBox in my master page.  Content pages are arranged accoring to business area folders, i.e. '~/Branding/Contracts.aspx'.  I find that when I load such a content page, jQuery, which is referenced in the master page as below, does not load.  I assume that this is because the browser is requesting 'Branding/Scripts/jQuery    '.  What can I do about this?  I don't have the 'root' operator in a plain 'script' tag.

```
<script src="/Scripts/jquery-1.3.2.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="Scripts/jquery-1.3.2.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="Scripts/jquery-ui-1.7.2.custom.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Use this in your `MasterPage`

```
<script src="<%= ResolveUrl("~/Scripts/jquery-1.3.2.js") %>" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

Please let me know if you are facing any trouble further.

Comment: My Two cents. The `<script>` tag must be closed properly. That is, it should have `<script></script>`. `<script />` will not work well with Server side code. I do not know why. But in my case, that was the problem

Answer (score 1):

One option is to "Outsource" your call to jQuery to something like [Googles AJAX libraries](http://code.google.com/intl/xx-bork/apis/ajaxlibs/documentation/). This will give you the added advantage of your clients possibly alreading having a cached version of jQuery.

I use http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.2.6/jquery.min.js

This wont help you if you have other custom scripts of course. For that I use the following on the page load event of the master page to load up my common sciprts.

```
        HtmlGenericControl myJs = new HtmlGenericControl(); 
        myJs.TagName = "script"; myJs.Attributes.Add("type", "text/javascript"); 
        myJs.Attributes.Add("language", "javascript"); //don't need it usually but for cross browser.
        myJs.Attributes.Add("src", ResolveUrl("~/scripts/jquery-ui-1.7.2.custom.min.js")); 
        this.Page.Header.Controls.Add(myJs);
```

Normally set up as a function with a paremter for the script path to make loading up multible js files easier.

Ode To Code has a fantatic article on Master Pages and this sort of thing:

http://odetocode.com/Articles/450.aspx

Answer (score 0):

I know this is old, but someone may come across it like I have. Anyways, you can register these scripts using the ASP ScriptManager object.

```
<asp:ScriptManager ID="ScriptManager" runat="server">
    <Scripts>
        <asp:ScriptReference Path="Scripts/jquery-1.8.3.js" />
        <asp:ScriptReference Path="Scripts/bootstrap.js" />
        <asp:ScriptReference Path="Scripts/general.js" />
    </Scripts>
</asp:ScriptManager>
```

This will keep let your scripts loading without using a Page.ResolveUrl. Just a preference I guess.