# Javascript not working after renaming asp.net page

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, highcharts

I am using highcharts library to render and draw my chart in javascript. I had it working just fine earlier but after renaming my page and relocating my page it now is not working. I have not touched the master page which loads the highcharts scripts and have not touched the script on the page. Any help would be appreciated!

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(DrawMyChart1);


    function DrawMyChart1 () {

        chart = new Highcharts.Chart({
            chart: {
                renderTo: 'newcustomerproc',
                defaultSeriesType: 'column',
                backgroundColor: '#2a2a2a'
            },
            title: {
                text: 'New Customer Process',
                style: { color: '#FFFFFF' }
            },
            xAxis: {
                categories: ['New Customer Process']
            },
            yAxis: {

                title: {
                    text: 'Stage in Process',
                    style: { color: '#FFFFFF' }
                }
            },
            legend: {
                itemStyle: { color: '#FFFFFF' }
            },
            tooltip: {
                pointFormat: '<span style="color:{series.color}">{series.name}</span>: <b>{point.y}</b> ({point.percentage:.0f}%)<br/>',
                shared: true
            },
            plotOptions: {
                column: { stacking: 'percent' }
            },
            series: [<%=Series1 %>],
            colors:[<%=Colors1 %>]
        });

    }
</script>
```

I also have debugged this in firebug and for some reason the $(document).ready() method is not firing.

```
<asp:Content ID="Content2" ContentPlaceHolderID="MainContent" Runat="Server">
<div class="widgetarea">
    <asp:Panel ID="TrainerDashboardPNL" runat="server" >

            <asp:HyperLink ID="HyperLink1" runat="server" NavigateUrl="~/Account/Achievements/AchievementList.aspx">
            <div class="widget_1x1 round">
                <div class="widget_header">
                    <h3>Achievements</h3>
                </div>
                <div class="widget_canvas">
                    <div id="achievementratiodiv" runat="server"></div>
                    <hr />
                    <div id="achievementtotaldiv" runat="server"></div>
                    <div id="achievementgoaldiv" runat="server"></div>
                </div>
            </div>
            </asp:HyperLink>

            <div class="widget_1x2 round">
                <div class="widget_header">
                    <h3>Performance Stats</h3>
                </div>
                <div class="widget_canvas">

                    <div class="widget_inner_canvas">

                        <div id="newcustomerproc" style="min-width: 50px; height: 270px; overflow:hidden;"></div>


                    </div>

                    <div class="widget_inner_canvas">
                        <div id="twoweekrankdiv" runat="server"></div>
                        <div id="twoweekscorediv" runat="server"></div>
                        <div id="todayscallsdiv" runat="server"></div>
                        <div id="todayscalltimediv" runat="server"></div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>

            <div class="widget_1x1 round">
                <div class="widget_header">
                    <h3>Training Level</h3>
                </div>
                <div class="widget_canvas">
                    <asp:Image ID="TrainingLevelIMG" runat="server" Height="250px" Width="250px" CssClass="center" /> 
                </div>
            </div>

            <div class="widget_1x1 round">
                <div class="widget_header">
                    <h3>Opportunities</h3>
                </div>
                <div class="widget_canvas">
                    <span class="widget_third_stat">Coming Soon</span>
                </div>
            </div>

            <div class="widget_1x1 round">
                <div class="widget_header">
                    <h3>Opportunity Payout</h3>
                </div>
                <div class="widget_canvas">
                    <span class="widget_third_stat">Coming Soon</span>
                </div>
            </div>

            <div>
                <div class="widget_1x1 round">
                    <div class="widget_header">
                        <h3>Training Potential</h3>
                    </div>
                    <div class="widget_canvas">
                        <div id="potentialearningsdiv" runat="server"></div>
                        <hr />                            
                        <div id="assignedhoursdiv" runat="server"></div>
                        <div id="payratediv" runat="server"></div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>

            <div class="widget_1x1 round">
                <div class="widget_header">
                    <h3>Training Hours</h3>
                </div>
                <div class="widget_canvas">
                    <div id="careerhoursdiv" runat="server"></div>
                    <div id="yearlytotaldiv" runat="server"></div>
                    <div id="nextleveldiv" runat="server"></div>
                </div>
            </div>
        <div class="clear" />

    </asp:Panel>
</div>
```

Comment: Did you check your error console? Is the master page loading jquery via a relative path that has changed since you move the file?

Comment: does your new page also builds 
series: [<%=Series1 %>],
colors:[<%=Colors1 %>]
properties correctly?

Comment: I did update the reference to the code behind. The [<%=Series1 %>], colors:[<%=Colors1 %>] are built correctly in the code behind with a javascript serializer. I just tested the default chart on the page and it doesn't work. http://www.highcharts.com/demo/column-stacked-percent

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After pulling my hair out for the last couple of days I finally figured out why it wasn't working. It turns out my scripts were not loading properly in the master page because my page was located in a child folder. This is what helped me solve my problem. [jQuery not loading on Master Page when the Content Page is in a child folder](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2598182/jquery-not-loading-on-master-page-when-the-content-page-is-in-a-child-folder)

Answer (score 0):

When you renamed the file, did you update the reference to the codebehind in the .aspx page declaration?